# Adding textfile from ASP to HTML textarea - Server crashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, text

When I try to add text from a ASP streamreader to a HTML textarea it writes the whole file correctly to the textarea. But then it loses connection with the ASP side server.

Smaller files are working fine but files bigger than 1kb makes the server crash/lose connection.

```
public void OpenFileASP(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string TextFromFile = FileManager1.SelectedItems[0].PhysicalPath;
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TextFromFile);

    TextArea.InnerText = "";
    foreach(string line in lines) {
        TextArea.InnerText += "\n" + line;
    }
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Alternatively; how would you send a text from ASP server side to HTML client side?

Comment: The connection dies/server dies. When I click something it just loads forever, because server/connection is lost.

But this is after everything loaded correctly.

Comment: Instead of setting the InnerText value in the foreach, have you tried appending to a stringBuilder and then setting the (final) string value to InnerText?

Comment: Doesn't work. 

You know any more alternative ways to send information from server side to client side I can try?

Comment: Instead of foreach, try `TextArea.InnerText = String.Join("\n",lines);`

Comment: That is the same thing as I am doing

MainTextBox.InnerText += "\n" + line;

I don't think that will help me with the server crashing/loosing connection.

Comment: It doesn't crash when I send to a <div> but to a textarea.